# Appending strings using << does not work as expected, but using + does

Tags: ruby

I have the following code which is causing me problems around the line I've marked.

```
arr = 'I wish I may I wish I might'.split

dictionary = Hash.new

arr.each_with_index do |word, index|
  break if arr[index + 2] == nil

  key = word << " " << arr[index + 1] #This is the problem line 
  value = arr[index + 2]

  dictionary.merge!( { key => value } ) { |key, v1, v2| [v1] << v2 }
end
puts dictionary
```

Running this code, I would expect the following output:

```
{"I wish"=>["I", "I"], "wish I"=>["may", "might"], "I may"=>"I", "may I"=>"wish"}
```

However, what I instead get is

```
{"I wish"=>["I may", "I"], "wish I"=>["may I", "might"], "I may"=>"I wish", "may I"=>"wish I"}
```

I've found that if I replace the problem line with

```
key = word + " " + arr[index + 1]
```

Everything works as expected. What is it about the first version of my line that was causing the unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [String#<<](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) method modifies the original object on which it is called. 
Here that is the object referred to by your `word` variable which is just 
another reference to one of the Strings in the `arr` Array. You can see this 
effect with the code:

```
 a = 'Hello'
 b = a << ' ' << 'World'
 puts a.__id__
 puts b.__id__
```

So when you use that method in one pass through the iterator it affects the 
following passes as well.

On the other hand the [String#+](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-2B) method creates a new String object to hold 
the combined strings. With this method one pass through the iterator has no 
effect on other passes.

Answer (score 1):

> key = word << " " << arr[index + 1]

The problem is that [String#<<](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) performs an in-place operation so the string is modified the next time it's used. On the other hand [String#+](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-2B) returns a new copy.

You have been bitten by an imperative side-effect (which is not unusual since side-effects are a huge source of bugs. Unless there are very compelling performance reasons, a [functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) approach yields better code). For example, that's how it could be written using `each_cons` and `map_by` from Facets:

```
words = 'I wish I may I wish I might'.split
dictionary = words.each_cons(3).map_by do |word1, word2, word3|
  ["#{word1} #{word2}", word3]
end
```